# Trying to a concatenation from two arrays and set value in another column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ecmascript-6

I'm not a developer but I work with Google Apps Script to create reports from Sheet files (which I'm better at). Something is wrong with what I try to do.

EDIT : Here is an example of the Sheet file (days are in french) - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ITXCvShSeDNSTcaA2nLqhaX18Qj45nkk5AsU9YyMIeA/edit?usp=sharing

I have a range of data (600 lines and 4 columns each), they are the same size. One as information about Days, the other about Hours. They are all in different ranges. I could use `setFormula` from Google script but I wanted to `CONCATENATE` the data from a script.

Basically I just want to do a thumbnail in a single column where I write each line of my two multidimensional arrays but merged them this time.

Somehow, this doesn't work.... I'm certainly making rookie mistakes here but I would love to understand my mistake it would help for lots of other things. Can't seem to put my finalarray together.

```
let i=0;
let j=0;
       
let valueToPush="";
let finalArray = new Array();
let day = currentSheet.getRange(4,5,lastRow,4).getValues();
let hour = currentSheet.getRange(4,10,lastRow,4).getValues();

   for (i=0;i<day.length;i++){
        valueToPush="";
        for (j=0;j<day[i].length;j++){
           valueToPush = day[i][j]+" : "+hour[i][j];
        }
       finalArray.push(valueToPush);
       
   }
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet without personal information to see the structure you have on it?

Comment: Here is a example, days of the week are in French : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ITXCvShSeDNSTcaA2nLqhaX18Qj45nkk5AsU9YyMIeA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This `currentSheet.getRange(4,5,lastRow,4).getValues();` should be this `currentSheet.getRange(4,5,lastRow-3,4).getValues();`

day and hour are exactly the same array

if you want finalArray to be a column it should be: `finalArray.push([valueToPush]);`

Comment: I'm sorry I realize I made a mistake in my original post, I've corrected :

let day = currentSheet.getRange(4,5,lastRow,4).getValues();
let hour = currentSheet.getRange(4,10,lastRow,4).getValues();

The array have different range ofc....

Answer (score 0):

if I could understand your need, please consider following code:

```
  const sht           = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Página19");
  const rowInit       = 1;
  const rowFinal      = 3;
  const columnFirst   = 1;
  const columnFinal   = 2;

  var data            = sht.getRange(rowInit,columnFirst,rowFinal,columnFinal).getValues();
  var outputArray     = [];

 // as many rows...
  data.forEach(d=>{
    var _tempArray=[];
    // as many cols
    d.forEach(e=>{
      _tempArray.push(e);
    });
    outputArray.push(_tempArray.join(":"));
  });

 Logger.log(outputArray)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I realize I made a mistake in my original post, I've corrected : let day = currentSheet.getRange(4,5,lastRow,4).getValues(); let hour = currentSheet.getRange(4,10,lastRow,4).getValues(); The array have different range ofc.... –

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating the values correctly.

Instead of using `day[i][j]+" : "+hour[i][j]`you should just use `day[i]+" : "+hour[i]` to get the correct combination of values to the last `Logger`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var lastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow();

  let valueToPush="";
  let finalArray = new Array();
  let day = currentSheet.getRange(2,5,lastRow,4).getValues(); 

  let hour = currentSheet.getRange(2,10,lastRow,4).getValues();

  for (let i=0;i<day.length;i++){
    valueToPush = day[i]+" : "+hour[i];
    finalArray.push(valueToPush);    
  }
  Logger.log(finalArray)
}
```

Comment: Ok, that explains a lot from my misunderstandings. I thought I was in a multidimensional array (or what I tjink it is). I still have a lot to figure out. Thank you !